# c# htmlagilitypack get table values

Tags: c#, sql-server, html-agility-pack

I have a webpage that needs to parsed ad values to be stored in sqlserver db. I have tried to use HTMLagility pack.

```
HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlDocument();
hdoc.LoadHtml(HTML);
var cols = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='results']//tr//th//td");
for (int i = 0; i < cols.Count; i = i + 2)
{
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string name = cols[i].InnerText.Trim(); 
}
```

This is how my html looks

```
<table id="results">
    <tr>
        <th style="white-space: nowrap;">
            ID
        </th>
        <th style="text-align: left;">
            Entity Name /<br>
            Type
        </th>
        <th style="white-space: nowrap;">
            Registered<br>
            Effective Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Status /<br>
            Status Date
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="exactMatch" valign="top">
        <td class="entityID">
            123456
        </td>
        <td class="nameAndTypeDescription">
            <span class="name"><a href="test.aspx?entityID=123456&hash=2055339395&orgTypes=01%2c99">
                NAME1 COMPANY </a></span>
            <br />
            <span class="typeDescription">55 - TRadeUnion Company </span>
        </td>
        <td class="registeredEffectiveDate">
            01/12/1912
        </td>
        <td class="statusDescriptionAndStatusDate">
            <span class="statusDescription">Exists Now </span>
            <br>
            <span class="statusDate">12/14/1943</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="exactMatch" valign="top">
        <td class="entityID">
            A23456
        </td>
        <td class="nameAndTypeDescription">
            <span class="name"><a href="test.aspx?entityID=A23456&hash=615278445&orgTypes=01%2c99">
                TESTA, INC. </a></span>
            <br />
            <span class="typeDescription">09 - Domestic Corporation </span>
        </td>
        <td class="registeredEffectiveDate">
            04/29/1926
        </td>
        <td class="statusDescriptionAndStatusDate">
            <span class="statusDescription">Dissolved Company </span>
            <br>
            <span class="statusDate">06/16/1998</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to insert entityID,name, hyperlink, type description,registeredeffectivedate,status description,status date. Right now they all print in one single line and I do know how to parse it. Please help.

Thanks
MR

Answer (score 1):

The TD's are not nested under TH's.

Try this: `SelectNodes("//table[@id='results']/tr/td");`

Comment: I did that. I get a column count as 8(2 rows * 4 columns)in the for loop. How can I store row by row in database??

Comment: I showed you how to extract the data from an HTML table using HTMLAgility pack.  Having someone teach you how to insert data into a database is beyond the scope of a single question.  Give it a try, when you get stuck, post another question.

Comment: This is what I wrote :var cols = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='results']/tr/td");

            for (int i = 0; i < cols.Count; i = i + 4)
            {  dr=dt.NewRow(); dr["id"]=cols[i].InnerText; dr["detaillink"]=cols[i+1].InnerHtml; this inner html contains span class. How can I use SelectNodes for this innerhtml??

Comment: I got it ...I was assigning table values to wrong variable..thanks for your time